# model dissmissviewcontroller or present another model error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have facebook connect in my app ;
once the user opened the app the masterViewController become active ;
I checked if the the user logged in inside the masterViewController if not logged I presented the model view controller of the facebook login
then iside facebooklogin controller when user press the connect via facebook and the facebook return success i want to present another view controller to confirm some information ; I presented the facebook in masterviewController by this code

```
if( ![user islogged] )
{
    self.fbLogin = [[facebookLogin alloc] initWithNibName:@"facebookLogin" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:fbLogin animated:YES];
}
```

and inside the facebooklogin controller "request did load" delegate i wrote

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

       if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && ([result count] > 0)) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
       }

       NSLog(@"user data %@",result);

       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        userData = nil;
        nameID  = nil;
}
```

but the model does not return , and i also tried to present another model from in the facebook request did load but it is also does not respond, please advice how i can present another model then dismiss it in this case?

Comment: I think you should use [self presentModalViewController] self being a UIViewController not a UINavigationViewController. This might be causing an error.

Comment: I used it but it has the same problem , if you can help me in this behavior : if i added button to do that, every thing is work but by doing it by any function that run automatically it does not work!